# How to set cells wrapped in "<strong>" elements in tableEL bold in jsPDF autotable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am using jQuery version 3.5.1, jspdf v2.5.1, and jspdf-autotables v3.5.28 to generate a PDF from an HTML table. The HTML table is gathered from localStorage (this is not really relevant, `table`-variable contains a normal HTML table in HTML format) and contains`<td>`s with `<strong>` elements inside. These cells need to be bolded in the resulting PDF table. How can I achieve this using jsPDF autotable?

Here is the code I am using to generate the PDF:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#download_PDF').click(function() {
    const table = localStorage.getItem('table');
    const tableEl = document.createElement('div');
    tableEl.innerHTML = table.trim();
    const filename = 'test.pdf';

    const doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.autoTable({
      html: tableEl.querySelector('table'),
      startY: 50,
      margin: { top: 10 },
    });
    doc.save(filename);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-qZvrmS2ekKPF2mSznTQsxqPgnpkI4DNTlrdUmTzrDgektczlKNRRhy5X5AAOnx5S09ydFYWWNSfcEqDTTHgtNA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.5.28/jspdf.plugin.autotable.min.js" integrity="sha512-03CCNkeosDFN2zCCu4vLpu3pJfZcrL48F3yB8k87ejT+OVMwco7IH3FW02vtbGhdncS6gyYZ/duYaC/K62xQPQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

I would appreciate any help in achieving the desired result. Thank you in advance.